# grouping consecutive dates of absence for each employee

Tags: dax, grouping, powerpivot

I'm working in Excel PowerPivot and I have an absence data set where there is a row for each day of absence per employee.

I want to assign the first day of absence to each row where the previous employee ID is the same AND the previous absence date is consecutive (i.e. is the previous day).

My data set looks like this:

current dataset with column "Absence Start Date" being what i'm hoping to achieve (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTJ9w.png)

Any help would be hugely appreciated! :)

I have played around with Earlier etc but i'm just going round in circles!

I want to extract the first day of the absence occurrence (so the first date in the date range for that employee's specific absence) and add it to each row in that range.

| Employee ID | Time Off Date | First Date Occurrence | Absence Start Date | Time Off Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/02/2023 |  | 23/01/2023 | Hernia |
| 123 | 02/02/2023 |  | 23/01/2023 | Hernia |
| 123 | 01/03/2023 |  | 23/01/2023 | Hernia |
| 123 | 02/03/2023 |  | 23/01/2023 | Hernia |

Comment: Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77644739/edit) your question with a [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) and not an image.

Comment: In your example image, ID 1 - Bereavement, 25/05 - why is `Absence Occurrence ID` 22/05? 22/05 is not the previous day of 25/05. Same again for ID 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach but it involves two calculated columns.

1st Calculated Column called `FirstDateOccurrence`:

```
=
  var thisId = [Employee ID]
  var thisReason = [Time Off Reason]
  var thisDate = [Time Off Date]
  var prevRow = TOPN(1, FILTER('Table1', [Employee ID] = thisId && [Time Off Reason] = thisReason && [Time Off Date] < thisDate), [Time Off Date], DESC)
  var prevDate = CALCULATE(MAX([Time Off Date]), prevRow)
  // use this one if NETWORKDAYS is available
  // return IF(NETWORKDAYS(prevDate, thisDate) > 2, thisDate)
  return SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(prevDate), thisDate,
    WEEKDAY(prevDate, 2) = 5 && DATEDIFF(prevDate, thisDate, DAY) < 4, BLANK(),
    DATEDIFF(prevDate, thisDate, DAY) <> 1, thisDate
  )
```

2nd Calculated Column called `Occurrence ID`:

```
=
  var thisId = [Employee ID]
  var thisReason = [Time Off Reason]
  var thisDate = [Time Off Date]
  var prevRow = TOPN(1, FILTER('Table1', [Employee ID] = thisId && [Time Off Reason] = thisReason && [FirstDateOccurrence] <= thisDate), [FirstDateOccurrence], DESC)
  return CALCULATE(MAX([Time Off Date]), prevRow)
```

As an added bonus, the above uses `NETWORKDAYS` and so if a date is Friday, and the next is Monday, then it will consider them as siblings.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - i've added those in:

1st calculated column works, but NETWORKDAYS doesn't seem to be available.
2nd calculated column I get a syntax error annoyingly!

Any Ideas?

Comment: Regarding your previous question, Absence Occurrence ID is intended to be the first day of sickness repeated for each row - so the first day of that occurrence of sickness was 22/05. That's the result i'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: Sorry so i'm not sure i've explained the issue too well - my bad! 

For each row, i need to add the first date of that occurrence of sickness - so if an absence spans 01/01 - 04/01 (for example), where each date has it's own row, I need to create a column which displays the first date of sickness for each row - so in this instance, each row for the dates between 01/01 - 04/01 should display 01/01 as this was the first day of sickness. Hope that is a bit clearer :)   I have changed the title of the column to Absence Start Date.

Comment: I understood correctly (I think). The second column `Occurrence ID` is the column you are after. The `FirstDateOccurence` column can be hidden and is necessary to perform the column that you wanted. Which version of Excel are you using? If `NETWORKDAYS` isn't available, did the `FirstDateOccurrence` column return any values?

Comment: I've updated the answer above for `FirstDateOccurrence`, replaced `NETWORKDAYS` with `DATEDIFF` on the last line. Once this column is working, do a refresh and the second column should work itself out.

Comment: No it errored - so I swapped it out with datediff - which obviously isn't ideal given it's not working days, but I just wanted to get it returning something!

Comment: Ah my bad i missed some of the syntax off (smh) - i've sorted that and it's working now! Thank you so much - this issue has been plaguing me for a long time and I've finally got a way to work around it :D

Comment: Cool. I've updated the answer with an improvement for checking if prevDate was a Friday - so like for like replacement for `NETWORKDAYS`.

Comment: Ah thank you - sorry i'm probably being blind but where have you added that? I was trying to figure out the best way to make up for not being able to use networkdays so if you've added in a workaround for that then that's amazing :D

Comment: See the `SWICH` statement at the end of `FirstDateOccurrence `

Comment: Thank you so much :D that's perfect!!

Comment: So I think i've come across an issue with this - it's grouping some dates together that have the same day of the month, but different days. Is this because of the switch at the end that looks for friday/ monday to act as NETWORKDAYS?

Comment: Shouldn't be - can you share a couple examples of this happening?

Comment: Added to the thread :)

And sorry I meant same date of the month, but different *months*

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/owqey.png

Comment: Apologies i've just checked again and it turns out it is actually one occurrence so the grouping and calculated first date of sickness is indeed correct!

Comment: I have just posted a follow up question to this just fyi :) -didn't want to spam you with more comments etc but if you wanted to take a look, it's here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659960/alternative-to-network-days-for-rotating-shift-patterns-dax-powerpivot