# Alternative to network days for rotating shift patterns - DAX PowerPivot

Tags: variables, dax, powerpivot

I recently asked a question and had some brilliant help (Sam Nseir!).

I am working in PowerPivot and have successfully (with the aforementioned help) managed to assign the first date of an occurrence of sickness to each date in the occurrence (through the use of two calculated columns).

It also accounts for Fridays and Mondays and treats them as consecutive days (in the absence of the NETWORKDAYS function which isn't available).

However, I have now realised that we have rotating shift patterns for drivers. So, I need to amend the code to account for a variety of different patterns. I have a field which says which shift each of these workers is on (It's not all workers, only drivers so I still need to be account for the standard mon-fri) and I have tables (tabs) for each shift type (each different pattern) which lists all of the dates (row by row) between 2023 - 2026 that are worked on this shift pattern. So I am hoping to find a way to reference these tables to say which dates should be considered consecutive - it's extra tricky because they are *rotating* shift patterns so move by one day each week.

Example of a shift pattern (there is a separate table for each shift type (6 in total):

| Calendar Event | Start Date | Day | Weekday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shift 6 | 18/02/2023 | 7 | Sat |
| Shift 6 | 21/02/2023 | 3 | Tues |
| Shift 6 | 22/02/2023 | 4 | Weds |
| Shift 6 | 23/02/2023 | 5 | Thurs |
| Shift 6 | 24/02/2023 | 6 | Fri |
| Shift 6 | 27/02/2023 | 2 | Mon |
| Shift 6 | 28/02/2023 | 3 | Tues |
| Shift 6 | 01/03/2023 | 4 | Weds |
| Shift 6 | 02/03/2023 | 5 | Thurs |
| Shift 6 | 05/03/2023 | 1 | Sun |
| Shift 6 | 06/03/2023 | 2 | Mon |
| Shift 6 | 07/03/2023 | 3 | Tues |
| Shift 6 | 08/03/2023 | 4 | Weds |
| Shift 6 | 11/03/2023 | 7 | Sat |
| Shift 6 | 12/03/2023 | 1 | Sun |
| Shift 6 | 13/03/2023 | 2 | Mon |
| Shift 6 | 14/03/2023 | 3 | Tues |
| Shift 6 | 17/03/2023 | 6 | Fri |
| Shift 6 | 18/03/2023 | 7 | Sat |
| Shift 6 | 19/03/2023 | 1 | Sun |
| Shift 6 | 20/03/2023 | 2 | Mon |
| Shift 6 | 23/03/2023 | 5 | Thurs |
| Shift 6 | 24/03/2023 | 6 | Fri |
| Shift 6 | 25/03/2023 | 7 | Sat |
| Shift 6 | 26/03/2023 | 1 | Sun |
| Shift 6 | 29/03/2023 | 4 | Weds |
| Shift 6 | 30/03/2023 | 5 | Thurs |
| Shift 6 | 31/03/2023 | 6 | Fri |
| Shift 6 | 01/04/2023 | 7 | Sat |
| Shift 6 | 04/04/2023 | 3 | Tues |
| Shift 6 | 05/04/2023 | 4 | Weds |
| Shift 6 | 06/04/2023 | 5 | Thurs |
| Shift 6 | 07/04/2023 | 6 | Fri |
| Shift 6 | 10/04/2023 | 2 | Mon |
| Shift 6 | 11/04/2023 | 3 | Tues |
| Shift 6 | 12/04/2023 | 4 | Weds |

The current logic I have (worked out for me by some one else - not my own knowledge!):

Calculated Column 1 code -(FirstDateOccurrence:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l3Yq.png)

Calculated Column 2 code - Absence Start Date: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbJnO.png)

An example below of what these columns return:

| Employee ID | Time Off Date | Approved | Time Off Reason | FirstDateOccurrence | Absence Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 21/02/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 20/02/2023 |
| 123 | 22/02/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 20/02/2023 |
| 123 | 23/02/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 20/02/2023 |
| 123 | 27/02/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 27/02/2023 | 27/02/2023 |
| 123 | 28/02/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 27/02/2023 |
| 123 | 01/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 27/02/2023 |
| 123 | 02/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 27/02/2023 |
| 123 | 06/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 06/03/2023 | 06/03/2023 |
| 123 | 07/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 06/03/2023 |
| 123 | 08/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 06/03/2023 |
| 123 | 09/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 06/03/2023 |
| 123 | 13/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 13/03/2023 | 13/03/2023 |
| 123 | 14/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 13/03/2023 |
| 123 | 15/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 13/03/2023 |
| 123 | 16/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 13/03/2023 |
| 123 | 20/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 20/03/2023 | 20/03/2023 |
| 123 | 21/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 20/03/2023 |
| 123 | 22/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 20/03/2023 |
| 123 | 23/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 20/03/2023 |
| 123 | 27/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 27/03/2023 | 27/03/2023 |
| 123 | 28/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 27/03/2023 |
| 123 | 29/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 27/03/2023 |
| 123 | 30/03/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 27/03/2023 |
| 123 | 03/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 03/04/2023 | 03/04/2023 |
| 123 | 04/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 03/04/2023 |
| 123 | 05/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 03/04/2023 |
| 123 | 06/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 03/04/2023 |
| 123 | 10/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress | 10/04/2023 | 10/04/2023 |
| 123 | 11/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 10/04/2023 |
| 123 | 12/04/2023 | 1 | Anxiety/Stress |  | 10/04/2023 |

So essentially, I am hoping to achieve the above but also accounting for the rotating shift patterns where an occurrence spans the 'off' days and into the next shift period - so then it is all counted as the same sickness occurrence - like when an absence spans over a weekend for a standard working week.

Any help hugely appreciated - I hate sickness data haha.

Comment: Where is the field for the shift pattern for a driver? And will a driver always have the same shift pattern?

Comment: And it would be useful, if you could update the question and include shift 6 rows to that span the same dates as the second table, to help with testing.

Comment: Hiya - the field for the shift pattern is in the same table as the absences table (second table above). These patterns do change, but they will update in the report whenever it is refreshed on a monthly basis. But the shift patterns in the actual shift tables shouldn't change - they span 2023-2026 currently and the dates will stay the same, but drivers may move between them (and back onto a regular 9-5). I'll update the question examples :) bear with

Comment: Question updated :) 

The shifts are all 4 on, 2 off if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try updating the `FirstDateOccurrence` calculated column with:

```
=
  var thisId = [Employee ID]
  var thisReason = [Time Off Reason]
  var thisDate = [Time Off Date]
  var thisShift = [Shift]
  var prevRow = TOPN(1, FILTER('Table1', [Employee ID] = thisId && [Time Off Reason] = thisReason && [Time Off Date] < thisDate), [Time Off Date], DESC)
  var prevDate = CALCULATE(MAX([Time Off Date]), prevRow)
  
  var shiftDiff = SWITCH(thisShift,
    1, COUNTROWS(FILTER('Shift 1', 'Shift 1'[Start Date] >= prevDate && 'Shift 1'[Start Date] <= thisDate)),
    2, COUNTROWS(FILTER('Shift 2', 'Shift 2'[Start Date] >= prevDate && 'Shift 2'[Start Date] <= thisDate)),
    3, COUNTROWS(FILTER('Shift 3', 'Shift 3'[Start Date] >= prevDate && 'Shift 3'[Start Date] <= thisDate)),
    4, COUNTROWS(FILTER('Shift 4', 'Shift 4'[Start Date] >= prevDate && 'Shift 4'[Start Date] <= thisDate)),
    5, COUNTROWS(FILTER('Shift 5', 'Shift 5'[Start Date] >= prevDate && 'Shift 5'[Start Date] <= thisDate)),
    6, COUNTROWS(FILTER('Shift 6', 'Shift 6'[Start Date] >= prevDate && 'Shift 6'[Start Date] <= thisDate))
  )
  
  return SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(prevDate), thisDate,
    shiftDiff = 2, BLANK(),
    ISBLANK(thisShift) && WEEKDAY(prevDate, 2) = 5 && DATEDIFF(prevDate, thisDate, DAY) < 4, BLANK(),
    DATEDIFF(prevDate, thisDate, DAY) <> 1, thisDate
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that looks like it's doing the job!

I was getting a syntax error on the RETURN section so i've edited it to:
    RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISBLANK(prevDate), thisDate,
    shiftDiff = 2, BLANK(),
If(ISBLANK(thisShift) && WEEKDAY(prevDate, 2) = 5 && DATEDIFF(prevDate, thisDate, DAY) < 4, BLANK(),IF(
    DATEDIFF(prevDate, thisDate, DAY) <> 1, thisDate)


Not sure if that's right?

Comment: Updated answer above to fix the syntax error. No need for `IF` within `SWITCH`